react-create-app project console error hot-update.js
I'm having problems with vscode too.
1-when I do ctrl+s, the changes I made in html and js are not visible in the live server.
2-when i develop a project with react-create-app, html is also updated when I do ctrl+s, console.when I log in, it adds, but it's a new console.when I log in, it does not delete the past ones, but prints the console along with the new ones, next to the old ones (main.0cb52cfc4cadee32d56a.hot-update.js) writes something like this.enter image description here
deleted try-1 , try and try-2 are writtenenter image description here

Please add some code so that contributor can help you better also explanation of your question is very confusing, refine it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
